# How to convert ReStructuredText docs to ipython notebooks?

Tags: python, documentation, ipython, restructuredtext

A lot of documentation in the python community these days is written in ReStructuredText. I want to convert some of these docs to ipython notebooks so that it is possible to not just read the examples in the docs, but interact with them immediately.

How can I convert ReStructuredTexts to ipython notebooks? Is there any way to do this? Maybe using pandoc as an intermediate step?

I have already read [some docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.0.0/interactive/nbconvert.html) on how to convert ipython notebooks to other formates, but I am interested in doing it the other way around, from rst to iptyhon. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you are still looking for a solution, we are building a Sphinx extension to convert a collection of RST files to Jupyter notebooks.

[sphinxcontrib-jupyter](https://github.com/QuantEcon/sphinxcontrib-jupyter)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [sphinxcontrib-jupyter](https://github.com/QuantEcon/sphinxcontrib-jupyter)/[jupinx](https://medium.com/quantecon-blog/introducing-jupinx-60ba9fc12f4f), Google found [rst2ipynb](https://pypi.org/project/rst2ipynb/). It seems to use pandoc. I haven't yet tried it myself though.

Answer (score 1):

There's a package for markdown to ipynb. [notedown 1.0.3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/notedown/1.0.3). You could use pandoc for rst to md then md to ipynb.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried this and it does not work because pandoc turns rst `>>>`'s into `\>\>\>` rather than a code block. Any suggestions?

Comment: I ran pandoc 1.11.1 Linux on https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/doc/src/guide.rst and got`>>>` rather than `\>\>\>` in the doctest blocks. I'm not sure where the escapes are coming from. The codeblocks execute in Ipy even though the interactive prompts remain. I agree it would look better if they were were stripped, but I dont know of any readymade solution.  Noticed another problem in the code blocks. notedown is splitting  blocks because there's no indent on the blank lines. It's pretty easy to merge the cells after the fact but you'd have to do at least some manual editing.